# Java spacing: Getting error while assigning values

Tags: java, syntax

I'm learning Java deep basics. I have one doubt.

Example code:

```
public static void main(String arg)
{

    int i=1++1; /* this is not working*/

    int i=1+ +1; /* this is working*/

}
```

Please explain what is going on...

Comment: 1++1 is not correct syntax. the second example is 1+ (+1) = 2

Comment: `++` is an increment operator so first line is probably evaluated as int i =(1++)1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the compilation the Java source (after unicode translation) undergoes a lexical translation as described in [Java Language Specification, chapter 3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html). Lexical translation is used to split the program into the sequence of so-called "input elements". Thus the `int i=1++1;` line is split to the following elements:

- `int`: token/keyword
- `<space>`: whitespace
- `i`: token/identifier
- `1`: token/literal
- `++`: token/operator
- `1`: token/literal
- `;`: token/separator

At this point compiler knows very little about the meaning of these tokens. However it cannot split the `++` operator to two separate operators as it's documented in [JLS 3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2):

> The **longest possible translation** is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.
>
> Thus, the input characters `a--b` are tokenized (§3.5) as `a`, `--`, `b`, which is not part of any grammatically correct program, even though the tokenization `a`, `-`, `-`, `b` could be part of a grammatically correct program.

Emphasis mine.

It's also documented in [JLS 3.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5) the possible usage of whitespace to separate tokens:

> White space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) can serve to separate tokens that, if adjacent, might be tokenized in another manner. For example, the ASCII characters `-` and `=` in the input can form the operator token `-=` (§3.12) only if there is no intervening white space or comment.

This explains why `1+ +1` is interpreted in different manner. You can also use the comment: `1+/**/+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the explanation:

```
int i=1++1; /* this is not working*/
```

This is not working because the parser is interpreting `++` to mean the increment operator, and you can't apply it to a constant.  It has to be applied to an integer or long type variable.

I'd recommend reading about [Java operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) more carefully.

```
int i=1+ +1; /* this is working*/
```

This works because the parser interprets this to mean 'add +1 to 1', which is 2.

In either case, these are examples of hard to read and interpret code.  You should learn a clear style with appropriate spacing and stick to it.

Comment: The question is *why* parser does so. Is it documented in JLS that parsing goes this way?

Comment: Thank for ur detailed answer! :)

Comment: @PrakashBala Please Accept this answer if it is answering your question.

Comment: As I've already pointed out, the ++ operator cannot be applied to r-values. It's well described in the docs.

Comment: @TagirValeev Yes, it [says so in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2).

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I found this earlier, check my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the first case:

> int i=1++1; /* this is not working*/

- **1** is interpreted as a number
- **++** is interpreted as **unary increment operator**
- **1** is interpreted as a number

so you have error at compile time like this:

```
  Multiple markers at this line
- Invalid argument to operation ++/--
- The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
- Syntax error on token "++", invalid AssignmentOperator
```

In the second case:

> int i=1+ +1; /* this is working*/

the *space* between **+** and **+** determines a different tokenization

- **1** is interpreted as a number
- **+** is interpreted as **additive operator**
- **+** is interpreted as **additive operator**
- **1** is interpreted as a number

See [Java tutorial operators chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)